Find the length of a line segment in a triangle
I'm a middle-school student. As some sort of challenge, my maths teacher gave us the problem that follows:

$\triangle ABC$ is a triangle such that $AB=84$ and $AC=28$. Let $D$ be a point on the line segment $BC$, such that $\angle CAD=\angle BAD=60^\circ$. What is the length of AD?

I've tried drawing an altitude from the vertex $B$, just to form a right triangle $\triangle EAB$ whom I figured out the lengths based on the sine and cosine of $60^\circ$. Then, I found $BC$ applying Pythagoras in the other right triangle that has been formed: $\triangle ECB$. Yet still I didn't come close to finding $AD$, so any help or hint are much is much appreciated. Note that I can't use the cosine rule as I haven't learned it yet

You've indicated in your comment that

Can we approach the problem without using the cosine rule though? I didn't learn about that yet, I only studied sin and cos in right triangles so far.

Also, when asked if you were familiar with using the sine function to find the triangle area, e.g., $S_{\triangle ABC}=\frac{1}{2}(ab\sin(\angle C))$, you stated in your commment that "Unfortunately no".
Thus, this solution uses only the the sin and cos in specific right triangles, specifically $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$ ones having side lengths in ratios of $1$, $\sqrt{3}$ and $2$, as well as isosceles and similar triangle properties, so I trust these techniques are more familiar to you.
As shown in the diagram below, extend $AC$ to $G$ so that $\lvert AG\rvert = \lvert AB\rvert = 84$, so $\lvert CG\rvert = 84 - 28 = 56$. Also, add the line segment $BG$. In addition, extend $AD$ to meet $BG$ at $E$, and add the vertical line segment of $CF$, with $F$ on $BG$.

Since $\triangle BAG$ is isosceles (with $\measuredangle EBA = \measuredangle EGA$), and $AE$ is an angle bisector, then $\measuredangle AEB = \measuredangle AEG = 90^{\circ}$ (e.g., as explained in Geometric proof - bisector of triangle). Thus, since  $\measuredangle BAE = \measuredangle GAE = 60^{\circ}$, we also have $\measuredangle ABE = \measuredangle AGE = 30^{\circ}$, so
$$\lvert AE \rvert = \frac{84}{2} = 42, \;\; \lvert BE \rvert = \lvert GE \rvert = 84\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = 42\sqrt{3} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
With $\triangle GCF$ also being a $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$ one, then
$$\lvert CF \rvert = \frac{56}{2} = 28, \;\; \lvert FG \rvert = 56\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = 28\sqrt{3} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
Using \eqref{eq1A}, we get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& \lvert EF\rvert = \lvert EG\rvert - \lvert FG\rvert = 42\sqrt{3} - 28\sqrt{3} = 14\sqrt{3} \\
& \lvert BF\rvert = \lvert BE\rvert + \lvert EF\rvert = 42\sqrt{3} + 14\sqrt{3} = 56\sqrt{3}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
Next, $\triangle BDE$ being similar to $\triangle BCF$ means that
$$\frac{\lvert DE\rvert}{\lvert CF\rvert} = \frac{\lvert BE\rvert}{\lvert BF\rvert} \;\to\; \frac{\lvert DE\rvert}{28} = \frac{42\sqrt{3}}{56\sqrt{3}} \;\to\; \lvert DE\rvert = 28\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) = 21 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
Finally, using this and \eqref{eq1A}, we get
$$\lvert AD\rvert = \lvert AE\rvert - \lvert DE\rvert = 42 - 21 = 21 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Very clever solution, but I have a question, when we extend AD to meet BG at E, how do we show that the line (AE) has to be perpendicular to the line (BG) as shown in your diagram?

@Karl Thanks for the compliment. Regarding your question, I've added a link to another question here which explains that. In particular, because $\measuredangle AEB = 180^{\circ} - \measuredangle EAB - \measuredangle EBA$ and $\measuredangle AEG = 180^{\circ} - \measuredangle EAG - \measuredangle EGA$ means, with $\measuredangle EAB = \measuredangle EAG$ and $\measuredangle EBA = \measuredangle EGA$, that $\measuredangle AEB = \measuredangle AEG$, so with them adding up to a straight line angle of $180^{\circ}$, they each must be $90^{\circ}$.

Oh it makes so much more sense now, thank you so much again

Based on Angle bisector theorem we have $\dfrac{BD}{CD}=\dfrac{28}{84}=\dfrac13$. Hence $BD$ and $CD$ are denoted as $a$ and $3a$ respectively.

Now apply the cosine rule for $\triangle ACD$ and $\triangle ABD$,
\begin{cases} {CD^2=AC^2+AD^2-2(AC)(AD)\cos(\angle CAD)} \\ {BD^2=AB^2+AD^2-2(AB)(AD)\cos(\angle BAD)} \end{cases}
Which is equivalent to,
\begin{cases} {9a^2=x^2+84^2-84x} \\ {a^2=x^2+28^2-28x} \end{cases}
Now, in order to find $x$, it is enough to solve $x^2-84x+84^2=9(x^2-28x+28^2)$. Note that the constant terms can be simplified as $9\times28^2=(3\times28)^2=84^2$,
$$8x^2-6\times28x=0 \Rightarrow x^2-21x=0\Rightarrow x=0\quad\text{or}\quad x=21$$
Where $x=21$ is obviously the answer.

Can we approach the problem without using the cosine rule though? I didn't learn about that yet,  I only studied sin and cos in right triangles so far. Thanks in advance

@Karl Are you familiar with finding area of triangle using sine function? (i.e $S_{\triangle ABC}= 1/2ab\times\sin(\angle C)$) I'm referring to method $3$ of Gwen's answer.

Unfortunately no

Ok, now I believe it is harder to solve the problem without these tools! You should edit your post and mention that you are looking for answers without cosine rule and the aforementioned formula involving sine.

I did, hope it would help

Have you learnt about the angle bisector theorem :)
If $\angle CAD=\angle BAD=60°$,then $AC:CD=AB:BD$.  This gives us the fact that $BD=3CD$. Now we use law of cosines to find the value of $BC$.
$BC^2=AB^2+AC^2-2ABAC\cos 120°$
$\implies BC=28\sqrt{13}cm=4CD\\\implies CD=7\sqrt{13}cm,BD=21\sqrt{13}$
Finally we reapply this rule,
$CD^2=AC^2+AD^2-2ADAC\cos 60°$
$\implies AD^2-28AD+147=0$
Returning $AD=21,7$.
$BD^2=AB^2+AD^2-2ADAB\cos 60°$
$\implies  AD^2-84AD-1323=0$
Returning $AD=21,64$.
Hence $AD=21$ as it's the common root
Method 2
You can also directly take $AD=l$(say) and solve
$9(l²-28l+28²)=l²-84l-84²$
Method 3
This is by area theorem. Area of a triangle is given by $$\frac{1}{2}ab\sin c$$
This is the simplest method after using angle bisector theorem.
$CD:BD=1:3 \implies \triangle ACD:\triangle BAD=1:3$(area ratio)
Thus
$$4×(\frac{1}{2}×28×AD×\sin 60°)=\frac{1}{2}×84×28×\sin 120°\implies AD=21$$

If you know that $\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y + \sin y \cos x$ then the following is another approach.
Drop a vertical line from $A$ to $E$ on $BC$. This creates a right triangle whose hypotenuse is $AD$. Pythagorean theorem states that $AD^2 = AE^2 + DE^2$. If the angle between $AE$ and $AD$ is $a$, then the angle between $DE$ and $DA$ is $90^o-a$, the angle between $AB$ and $AE$ is $60^o-a$, the angle between $AB$ and $AC$ is $30^o + a$, and between $BC$ and $CA$ it is $30^o-a$.
The segment $DE$ has a length of $AD\cos(90^o-a)=AD\sin a$ and the segment $AE$ has a length of $28\sin(30^o+a)$. So the Pythagorean expression is $AD^2 = (28\sin(30^o+a))^2 + (AD\sin a)^2$. Rewriting the sine of a sum gives $AD^2 = (28\sin 30^o\cos a+\sin a \cos 30^o)^2 + (AD\sin a)^2$ and solving for $AD^2$ gives $AD^2 = 588\tan^2a + 392\sqrt{3}\tan a + 196$.
To determine $\tan a$ we can equate the height of $AE$ when viewed from the left and the right: $28\sin(30+a) = 84\sin (30-a)$. Expanding the sines and solving for $\sin a/\cos a = \tan a$ gives $\sqrt{3}/6$. Substituting this into the expression for $AD^2$ gives $588(1/12) + 392(1/2)+196 = 441$: so $AD=21$.
If we generalize the approach above with $s=28,l=84,A=(120/2)^o$ then we find
$$\tan a=\frac{l-s}{(l+s)\tan(A)}$$
$$AD = s\cos(A-a)/\cos(a)$$
and with a little simplification it is possible to eliminate the $a$ to give the pleasing result for the length of the angle bisector in terms of only the given sides and measure of the bisected angle (i.e. it is not necessary to use the law of cosines to calculate the length of the 3rd side).
$$AD = \frac{2ls}{l+s}\cos A$$
e.g. using the measures you were given,
$$\frac{2(84)(28)}{28+84}\frac12 = 21$$
